# C# Winform Auto Refresh: Every 5 Minutes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# WinForm application that I need to be refreshed every 5 minutes.

I have looked into Background Worker as well as, a Timer Class.

I was just wondering what is the best way to get main form refreshed so user updates can be displayed without having to close the application and reopening it.

Comment: Use the `Timer` class, this is what it is meant for. Btw, you should post some of your code, so people can help with a **specific** problem.

Answer (score 8):

that is called **polling** , you can use `Timer` control to do that.

**Step 1:** You need to Subscribe to the `Timer Tick` event.
**Step 2:** Set the `Interval` property of the `Timer` to `300000` milliseconds for raising the event for every 5 Minutes.
**Step 3:** In `Tick Event Handler`  just do whatever you want to perform.
**Step 4:** you can Call the  `timer1.Stop()` method whenever you want to stop the timer.

**Note** : if you don't `stop` the `timer` it becomes `infinite`.
if you want to `stop` the `timer` you can call `timer1.Stop();`

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer1.Interval=300000;//5 minutes
timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
timer1.Start();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //do whatever you want 
     RefreshMyForm();
}

private void RefreshMyForm()
{

  //update form with latest Data

}
```

Comment: Would it be the same for, if I have a chat application? Sending and receiving messages from users who are logged into the application. Open chat room or private chat?

Comment: it would be same, but you need to take care cross-threaded operations, if you can show us some code(if not avialble now-in future) we surly help you.

Comment: `timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);` and worth to mention, what `Windows.Forms.Timer` event occurs in *UI thread*, thus any *long* refreshing operation will block (freeze, stutter?) UI.

Comment: @Sinatr: no it does not hang the ui.

Comment: @user3324364: sure, all the best.